# What are the maximal chains and antichains of $S=\{0,1,4,6,7,8,9\}$ under the order of divisibility?

Tags: order-theory

I just really don't understand what 'maximal' is.

Comment: It just means that you can't add any more elements and still have a chain (or antichain.)

Comment: So $\{0\}$ is an example of a maximal anti-chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maximal chain is one that cannot be extended.

$1 \mid 4$ is not maximal because it can be extended to $1 \mid 4 \mid 8$.